# Nuxt.js: dispatch Vuex action not working with mapState

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to dispatch action in fetch hook in NuxtJS

```js
async fetch() {
  return await this.$nuxt.context.store.dispatch('settings/getSettings')
}
```

then

```html
<el-table v-if="!$fetchState.pending" :data="settings.colors">
 ...
</el-table>
```

them

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    loading: 'settings/loading',
    settings:'settings/settings'
  }),
}
```

In the end I get an error colours is undefined, But the code below works, without Vuex

```js
async fetch() {
  return await this.$axios.$get(EP_GET_DATA_SETTINGS).then((data)=>{
    this.settings = data
  })
}
```

Please advise how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mapState` with a Vuex module, the first argument is the module name:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState('settings', {
    loading: 'loading',
    settings:'settings'
  }),
}
```

Here is another way to do it with array syntax:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState('settings', ['loading', 'settings'])
}
```

Comment: thanks dan! saved me. I don't quite get the spread syntax part though

Comment: @Sharkfin It's good practice because without the spread, you'd be setting the whole `computed` block, and then couldn't add any non-Vuex computeds to that component  (ie.  `computed: mapState(...)`)

Comment: ah got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    loading: (state) => state.settings.loading,
    settings: (state) => state.settings.settings,
  }),
}
```

Comment: this also works